# Iterative construction of the real projective space

Tags: general-topology, visualization

I can [visualize the construction of $\mathrm{RP}^2$](https://youtu.be/x2SZSfYYSc8) from a disc $B^2$ whose boundary $S^1$ is subjected to the antipodal identification. This can be obtained by glueing the edge of a Möbius strip $M$, which is $S^1$, with the edge of the disc, after suitably deforming the disc to the shape of a punctured sphere. Thus,

$$ \mathrm{RP}^2 = M  \cup_{\circ} B^2$$

where $\cup_{\circ}$ denotes this glueing mechanism.

On the other hand, however, we know that $S^1$ subjected to the antipodal identification is $\mathrm{RP}^1 = S^1$. So there must be some mechanism $\cup_{?}$ such that $\mathrm{RP^{2}} = \mathrm{RP}^1 \cup_{?} B^2$. Or, more generally,

$$ \mathrm{RP^{n+1}} = \mathrm{RP}^n \cup_{?} B^{n+1} \,.$$

Does there exist any such construction? Alternatively, are there higher dimensional equivalents of Möbius strips $M^n$ such that $$ \mathrm{RP^n} = M^n \cup_{\circ} B^n \,? $$

P.S. I am not familiar with algebraic topology. So I would be most obliged if you explain in lay terms with respect to algebraic topology, should the need arise. My focus is on a visual understanding.

Comment: I guess you want to know about the [CW structure of real projective space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_space).

Comment: The superscript in $B^n$ corresponds to the dimension of the ball.  So if you are taking unions of balls to get some $\mathbb{R}P^{n+1}$, you need to be using the same dimension balls, $B^{n+1}$ and "higher dimensional" Möbius strip M $M^{n+1}$.

Comment: Unrelated to the first comment, this post might be what you are looking for: [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76816/how-do-you-visualize-real-projective-n-space?rq=1]

Comment: @N.Owad I meant the dimensions to be as you have started. I have corrected the typos. Anyway, thanks for the attached link.

Comment: seconding @Krish's comment. And if you don't care for wikipedia's description of it there is also a description on page 6 of Hatcher (https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) which again describes how to build $\mathbb{R}P^n$ from $\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$

Comment: @Krish Thanks for the link. :)

Comment: @Gage Thanks. I'll read on it.